# How does for in loop work with multiple sequences python

Tags: python, for-loop

I meet following code of for-loop, and not very sure how it goes:

```
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]
```

is it iterate through 'snippet' then 'phrase'?

EDIT:

```
PHRASES = {
"class %%%(%%%):":
  "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
"class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
  "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
"class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
  "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
"*** = %%%()":
  "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
"***.***(@@@)":
  "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
"***.*** = '***'":
  "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

##############
#'snippet' is a key in the dict shown above, and 'phrase' is its corresponding value
def convert(snippet, phrase):
class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
               random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
results = []
param_names = []

for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
    param_count = random.randint(1,3)
    param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

########
#Here is the code in question
########
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]

    # fake class names
    for word in class_names:
        result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

    # fake other names
    for word in other_names:
        result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

    # fake parameter lists
    for word in param_names:
        result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

    results.append(result)

return results
```

Comment: Please include a more complete example.

Comment: It's the same as `for sentence in (snippet, phrase)`. `sentence` will be set to `snippet` in the first iteration, and `phrase` in the second. You could have tested this out in about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

No. `snippet, phrase` defines a tuple of those two elements only. The iteration is over that tuple; ie sentence is first the value of `snippet` and then the value of `phrase`. It doesn't iterate through the contents of those values.

Comment: you say 'sentence is first value of ...' then you say 'it doesn't iterate through the contents of...'. What the difference of **content** and **value**?